# Fitting experimental data to a model described by a series of differential equations

Tags: matlab, equation, curve-fitting, ode

I have a series of experimental kinetic data in a form of `Concentration = f(time)`, namely:

- `L(time) = f0(time)`
- `A(time) = f1(time)`
- `B(time) = f2(time)`
- `C(time) = f3(time)`
- `D(time) = f4(time)`
- `P(time) = f5(time)`
- `A(time) + ... + P(Time) = known value`

I have a model represented as a system of differential equations:

```
dL/dt = -k_tot*MR3*(L)^2, where k_tot = k_LA + k_LB + k_LC + k_LD
dMR3/dt = -k_tot*MR3*L
dP/dt = k_AP*A + k_BP*B + k_CP*C + k_DP*D
dA/dt = 2*k_LA*MR3*(L)^2 - k_AP*A
dB/dt = 2*k_LB*MR3*(L)^2 - k_BP*B
dC/dt = 2*k_LC*MR3*(L)^2 - k_CP*C
dD/dt = 2*k_LA*MR3*(L)^2 - k_DP*D
```

I would like to use ODE model (`ode45`) in order to:

- find/estimate the `k_XY` (`k_LA`, `k_LB`, ..., `k_AP` etc)
- curve-fit the calculated data with the experimental ones.

The idea is to set up the ODE-based function, which would allow to fit a specified data for a specified diff.equation within the given system of equations.

Could someone help with the example of Matlab code, please?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: This can be formulated as optimal control problem, the objective function is the distance of the ODE solution to the data, the ODE is the constraints, and the parameters are the control variables. The principal idea is to solve the ODE forward, keep a trace of that computation, and accumulate the gradient of the objective function wrt. the parameters following the trace backwards. Then plug this into a gradient descent scheme like CG.

Comment: Thanks much! However, it will take months for me to workout the Matlab code and debug it...